# Which statistical method to use to compare Distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test

I was given a question for an assignment but I'm getting confused as to how I'd answer it correctly. The question states:

> A study was carried out to see if patients whose skin did not respond
>   to dinitrocholorobenzene (DNCB), a contact allergen, would show an
>   equally negative response to corton oil, a skin irritant (Roth et al.,
>   1975). The results of DNCB test were compared patients with different
>   stages of cancer, as shown in the following table.

[image]

> Q: Which methods of analysis could be used to compare the
>   distributions for Stage of skin cancer and DNCB reaction ?

The issue I'm having is I'm not sure what method I'm supposed to use!? I was thinking a paired t-test as paired t-tests are used when there are two measurements on the same experimental unit (as in this case there is either a positive or negative reaction). But I was also thinking that maybe a squared Chi-test might be more appropriate. I'm getting really confused about which method to use!

Comment: I do not think your reasoning about pairing is correct. If I understand your table it contains each patient exactly once leading to 173 patients in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a chisquare test to see if independence is a possible model, or, to get more information, use logistic regression with the "Stage of skin cancer" as covariable.  First I show the chisquare test done in R, in two ways, the second simulates the p-value conditional on the margins in the table ("Fisher exact test"):

```
rbind(dncb.pos, dncb.neg,n)
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
dncb.pos   39   39   26
dncb.neg   13   19   37
n          52   58   63
rpop  <-  dncb.pos/n
 prop
[1] 0.7500000 0.6724138 0.4126984  # so we can see it looks like a trend!

chisq.test(rbind(dncb.pos,dncb.neg))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rbind(dncb.pos, dncb.neg)
X-squared = 15.365, df = 2, p-value = 0.0004608

 chisq.test(rbind(dncb.pos,dncb.neg),sim=TRUE,B=20000)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 20000
    replicates)

data:  rbind(dncb.pos, dncb.neg)
X-squared = 15.365, df = NA, p-value = 0.00035
```

The null hypothesis of no relationship with the "Stage of skin cancer" is rejected.

Then we try a logistic regression, with a linear trend in proportions with the Stage variable:

```
Stage  <- c(1,2,3)
 mod  <-  glm(cbind(dncb.pos, dncb.neg) ~ Stage, family=binomial)
 summary(mod)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(dncb.pos, dncb.neg) ~ Stage, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3  
-0.4804   0.7987  -0.3718  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.0107     0.4775   4.211 2.54e-05 ***
Stage        -0.7562     0.2069  -3.655 0.000257 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 15.4451  on 2  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  1.0069  on 1  degrees of freedom
AIC: 18.104

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

 confint(mod)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  1.106614  2.9869535
Stage       -1.174053 -0.3599763
```

The trend seems to be clearly significant.  A serious analysis now must continue with other question, such as Is there overdispersion? some plots, looking at the residuals, .... which I leave for you.  (You could get a logistic regression analysis closer to the chisquare test by entering `Stage` as a factor variable, using `as.factor(Stage)` ).

A third option is just to calculate, for each group, binomial confidence intervals, and maybe plotting them. Could be done as below:

```
library(Hmisc)
confint <- binconf(dncb.pos,n,method="wilson")
confint
 PointEst     Lower     Upper
 0.7500000 0.6179354 0.8476685
 0.6724138 0.5442405 0.7791671
 0.4126984 0.2995847 0.5358468
# Plotting:
plot(c(0.5,3.5),0:1,type="n",xlab="Stage",ylab="Proportions",
      main="Confidence intervals (alpha=0.05)",xaxp=c(1,3,2))

points(Stage,confint[,1],cex=2,col="red")
 lines(c(1,1,NA,2,2,NA,3,3),c(confint[1,2:3],NA,confint[2,2:3],NA,confint[3,2:3]),col="skyblue") # NA used to break the lines
```

[image]